# Changing background color for diasabled check Box in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am working in an MFC windows application. I am using check boxes in Check List Box control (`CCheckListBox` class) . While disabling a check box, its color remains gray. Is there any way to change the background color from gray to another color?

Comment: Are you asking about an individual item, or, the entire control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [DrawItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84cw5ysf(v=vs.120).aspx) method to control the rendering of the control and its list items.  To do that, you’ll want to derive your own CCheckListBox class and implement that method.  For example, I’ve changed the second item in the list to red.

[image]

The sample code to do that looks like…

```
void MyCheckListBox::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)
{
    UINT index = lpDrawItemStruct->itemID;
    CDC *pDC = CDC::FromHandle (lpDrawItemStruct->hDC);
    if (index == 1)
    {
        CRect rect = lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem;
        pDC->FillSolidRect(&rect, RGB(255, 0, 0));
    }
    CString str;
    GetText(index, str);
    pDC->DrawText(str, &lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem, DT_LEFT | DT_VCENTER);
}
```

The above sample **only** changes the item’s background color.  I’ve left the rest of the processing and any extra rendering up to you.

Comment: This will not work if there  are more than 2 check boxes. Check it.

Comment: @SumanReddy DrawItem is called for **each** item that needs rendering in the list.  _lpDrawitemStruct_ contains the index and the CRect for the item that should be rendered.  It also contains the corresponding state (eg. disabled).  Please try a sample and step through the code.

Comment: once you change the background color of an item then same color will be reflecting for other items also. If you click on other items then background color is changed automatically

Comment: @SumanReddy  I'm not sure I understand your concern.  Your code can control the color that is used for **each** individual item.  My sample shows how to change an individual background item's color.  As I said, the structure that is passed is used for each item.  The method will be called for **every** item in the list.  You can use the state information to decide how you want to render the item.  Typically, you add conditional code to determine how the item should be rendered.  I hope this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

@rrirower's implementation will work but his code needs some modifications.

**(1) Changing the Back ground color of the disabled check Box**

```
void CMyCheckListBox::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)
{
  CDC dc;
  dc.Attach(lpDrawItemStruct ->hDC);
  RECT rect = lpDrawItemStruct ->rcItem;
  UINT nId=lpDrawItemStruct->itemID;
  CString strItemText;
  GetText(lpDrawItemStruct ->itemID, strItemText);
  if(nId==1 ||nId==3){
    dc.FillSolidRect(&rect,RGB(255,0,0));
    dc.DrawText(strItemText , &rect, DT_LEFT | DT_VCENTER);
  }
  else{
    CCheckListBox::DrawItem(lpDrawItemStruct); 
  } 
  dc.Detach();
}
```

[image]

**(2) Changing the Disabled check list box text color**
replace  `dc.FillSolidRect(&rect,RGB(255,0,0));` with `dc.SetTextColor(RGB(255,0,0));`

[image]

Comment: The first one is really bad usability. It hurts my eyes looking at it!

Comment: @sergiol  that's true. But that is actual requirement.